# JSON parsing of multidimensional JSON Object in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON on a page

```
{   
"users": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "age": "30",
        },
        {
            "name": "Dave",
            "age": "20",
        },
         ...
      ]
    }
```

I'm decoding it using `$json = json_decode($data);`. If  I want a loop that print every name and age for each user how can I do that?

I'm tring to do something like the following code but it's not working

```
foreach($json->users->name as $key => $result){
        $name = $result;
        $age = $result->age;

        echo $name;
        echo $age;
        echo "<br>";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I achieve that?

Comment: `print_r($json->users)` What do you see?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object in <file> on line 44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$string = "{\"users\": [{\"name\": \"BA8842_530\",\"age\": \"0.0\"},{\"name\": \"BA8842_540\",\"age\": \"20\"}]}";
$json = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ($json['users'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "Name: " . $value['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "Age: " . $value['age'] . "<br>";
}
```

The output would be:

```
// Output
Name: BA8842_530
Age: 0.0
Name: BA8842_540
Age: 20
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot, was going crazy hahah

Comment: @L.K. - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: Was waiting 5 minutes to do so ;)

Comment: Glad to know, that it helped you. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($json->users as $row){
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->age;
        echo "<br>";
}
```